# Difference between internet and Desktop java EE app server

Tags: ejb-3.0

I need some clarification. I know that in order to run a java EE project, one needs a java EE compliant application server, such as tomcat, jboss, glashfish, etc. But, i download these to my desktop, but how about when i run it online? Are Jboss, tomcat, glashfish, etc. application servers just for your desktop, or are these the app server internet service providers have as well. I am trying to use godaddy as my internet service provider; i called them, but the customer service guy didnt know what application server they had, or did i ask the wrong question? Or how can i know waht application server they have? Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What components of JavaEE are you planning to use? Are you really using EJB? EJB is use for distributed app and transaction management (mostly big enterprise app).

Answer (score 0):

There are few companies which provide a restricted Tomcat Web Server.

But in order to get a Java EE Application server, you will have to buy a virtual machine and there you can install any of the available Application Servers.